# assert properties of a object are non-null using a function's arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to achieve a type-safe API that takes a generic and only executes if a condition is met:

```
const doSomethingWith = (data: unknown) => data

const fn = <T extends unknown>(data: T, opts: { if: boolean }): void => {
  if (opts.if == false) return;

  doSomethingWith(data)
}
```

How can I make `opts.if` a valid predicate in this context? Consider the following cases:

```
type Data = { abc: string }

// should be valid - checks to make sure data.abc is non-null
const data: Partial<Data> = {}
fn<Data>(data, { if: data.abc != null  })

// should be valid - all data is given
const data2: Data = { abc: '123' }
fn<Data>(data2)

// should be invalid - no null check occurs
const data3: Partial<Data> = {}
fn<Data>(data3)
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJiAyiAtgUygCwJZgOYDq2WMAvDABRwCGU1AXDAK5gDWYIA7mAJRkB88WtQCwAKHGhIsAGZgyMADwAVGGgAeUNGDgRmbDt35VhjZQBoYIAA5QIAfkYBvGNhmMARiBAAbNNXkAXx5GADcQbDgBGCdxGFcZShs7ewA6NzJyGWofCDQ+ACcMJgKwAG5xOPgkVAwcfCIsEzoecUDKsSgAT2s0GAARYQUXag9gRmgC3DwYdokxAHoFmAhMECYfKI8+0JzImABaGGBMNGBWPSgQGBRqVj6IEr6aOlTR4Fc9DjADsA2fSTgaBCOiMAAK1AKUGwOUUgzognITjmcjhwmML2olhcbkYmLeYxgAEJyH8fD54sEOksVmsNlsdnsokcchTMZ8YHhsKFtIDpCDqAAmRjw6jDGDvRgAcgAjIKAMxS2biVGijHCQWteY01brTYwbauMC7Hz7I4cGBkiknM6sKzAYAlCB84GY+XgyHQ2Fq4YosBohHNajynhAA).

Comment: The goal of this utility function is not clear to me. Do you want to actually use data in the second argument as a [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to narrow the type within the function? If so, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzAQ1m) meet your needs? If not, can you edit your question to clarify what the real intent is?

Comment: This might be type-safe overkill, but here's my approach: https://tsplay.dev/NrKEzm

Comment: Probably you could also consider using [`strictNullCheck`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) in the `tsconfig.json` options, because `Partial<Data>` is the superset of `Data` but with a `undefined` union type in each property. With `strictNullCheck=true` you will always prevent the assignment of `Partial<Data>` to `Data` (from the compiler)

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by making the `opts.if` argument be a function as opposed to a static `boolean` value.

This way, it's very simple to make the predicate match the type of the data that is passed as first argument.

```js
const doSomethingWith = <T>(data: T) => data

const fn = <T>(data: T, opts?: { if: (t: T) => boolean }): void => {
  if (opts?.if(data) === false) return;

  doSomethingWith(data)
}

type Data = { abc: string }

const data: Partial<Data> = {}
const data2: Data = { abc: '123' }
const data3: Partial<Data> = {}


fn(data, { if: d => d.abc != null  }) // OK, valid predicate
fn(data2) // OK, no predicate
fn(data3, { if: d => d.foobar != null  }) // NOT OK, predicte doesn't match data
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=18&ssc=81&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJiAyiAtgUygCwJZgOYDq2WMAvDADwAqAfABRwCGUjAXDFQJRk3zOMBYAFDDQkWADMwZSrQb92VADQwQABygQA-OwDeMbBPZ0oi7qV4AjECAA2aRtIC+ndgDcQ2ODxi7hMAwkYOnVNLQA6Q3kWc3IJRlsING4AJwwAVxSwAG5hf3gkVAwcfCIsaMZOYSc8oSgATzU0GAARfhl9RktgdmgU3DwYGpEhMWg+FnYABUYUqGwEijaWXnJdYbHYJhYAJnZlxg6YLp6YAHIARh2AZjOh0XBx7cZr6dn5xYPV32HaqQqVPpDOxvBZ4OETjAAITkMDpWy2AIuGAAehRMAA8gBpFRuBJeGBqNJwbDAZhoYT-Z47bhozE4mBgECE4mk8mUsAVa6AwIgnxwcISGyWWbQ2HwxFDWnogByGKo9JURLQJOAUGaCDQEDAZ1gKGYwEwE0YQA)

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at this was [way over-complicated](https://tsplay.dev/NrKEzm).  But upon reading your question again, I think we can make this really simple.

#### Solution

You can require that your arguments are valid using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

```
function fn<T>(data: Partial<T>, opts: { if: boolean }): void
function fn<T>(data: T): void
function fn<T>(data: T, opts?: { if: boolean }): void {
  if (opts?.if == false) return;

  doSomethingWith(data);
}
```

The third `fn` line is the [implementation signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature), and the first two lines are the function signatures that you must match.

---

#### Explanation

All three of your examples expect that `doSomethingWith` will be called with a complete `Data` object.

If your `data` variable is incomplete then `opts` must be provided.  The first overload signature allows for `Partial<Data>` but requires `opts`:

```
function fn<T>(data: Partial<T>, opts: { if: boolean }): void
```

which matches example #1:

```
// should be valid - checks to make sure data.abc is non-null
const data: Partial<Data> = {}
fn<Data>(data, { if: data.abc != null  })
```

If we already know that the `data` variable is complete, then you don't need to provide any `opts`.  That is this signature:

```
function fn<T>(data: T): void
```

which matches example #2:

```
// should be valid - all data is given
const data2: Data = { abc: '123' }
fn<Data>(data2)
```

Your third example fails as expected because it does not match either of the overloaded function signatures.  Since we haven't provided an `opts` argument, the first argument must be a complete `Data` object.  But `data3` is `Partial<Data>` so we get an error:

```
// should be invalid - no null check occurs
const data3: Partial<Data> = {}
fn<Data>(data3)
```

```
Argument of type 'Partial<Data>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data'.
  Types of property 'abc' are incompatible.
   Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N9y2MN)